# Extra set of parens after a $(function() {...})

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code looking like so:

```
$(function() {
  // some code here to do stuff
})();
```

Any ideas what the extra () at the end contribute to? With or without them the script works fine.

I'm sure this has been discussed before but I don't know of a way to code-search SO.

Comment: search for immediate function. The brackets basically execute the function as soon as its defined.

Comment: @icktoofay ah yes your right. I didn't even think about the $ sign

Comment: @Wiseguy - Your name precedes you. I understand document.ready(). I was asking the significance of the extra ().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it's a typo.

**Either** (JQuery DOM Ready):

```
$(function() {
  // some code here to do stuff
});
```

**Or** (Self-invoking anonymous function):

```
(function() {
  // some code here to do stuff
})();
```

Comment: One of my pet peeves: why call the function self-invoking when clearly we are invoking it explicitly? Doesn't change the correctness of the answer though.

Comment: Guys - all good answers, @AlienWebGuy answered earliest so he gets the cred. Turns out just a typo.

Comment: @Stevus: Actually it was me but it's OK ;)

Comment: @Jon - You don't say what terminology you want to use instead, but I usually say "immediately executed anonymous function" (or sometimes "immediately invoked anonymouse function").

Comment: @Jon in all fairness your initial answer was just your first paragraph ;)

Comment: @Jon - sorry man - just noticed both you guys had the same answer post times.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Submitting a quick answer and improving it is something I see done a lot in SO. Anyway, this is IMHO nothing worth talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this would seem to produce a runtime error, because the jQuery object (which is returned by the `$(...)` call) is not a function itself. Therefore, attempting to invoke it is an error. Testing with a Javascript console will confirm this.

It looks like this code "combines" the ideas of setting up a document-ready callback with jQuery and wrapping initialization code in a function to obtain a separate scope, but the end result is simply an error.

Either this

```
$(function() { ... }); // document-ready callback with jQuery
```

or this

```
(function() { ... })(); // initialization code in its own scope
```

would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

With the `$` in the front, it doesn't mean much. It probably was supposed to be `$(function() {});` which is jQuery's way of calling a function when the dom is ready. It is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

With a JavaScript function, the extra set of parentheses call the function immediately.

```
(function() {
    alert( "hi" );
})();
```

is pretty much the same as

```
function fn() {
    alert( "hi" );
}
fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `$(function(){})()` as Jon posted (it will result with an error with jQuery - I could see `$(function(){}());` ) but in general when you see this the trailing () actually calls the function.

```
var a = 2;
(function() {
    a = 1;
})
alert(a);
```

Would result in 2 since the function is never called - it's just declared.

```
var a = 2;
(function() {
    a = 1;
})();
alert(a);
```

Results in 1 since the declared function is now called. This is typically done to create an anonymous function without having to explicitly declare it (e.g. `function doSomething();`) which tends to cloud up your namespace with frivolous utility functions.